# I need help parameterizing some VBScript code in an .asp file

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

Here is a snippet of what I'm working on. Please let me know if I need to post more:

```
<% @ LANGUAGE = VBScript ENABLESESSIONSTATE = False %>

 <!--#include file="Connections/ConnectionString.asp" -->
 <!--#include file="SqlCheckInclude.asp" -->

<%
     Dim LoginTest
     LoginTest = ""

    If Request.QueryString("Action") = "Login" Then
        Dim IsUserNameLocked
        Set IsUserNameLocked = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        IsUserNameLocked.ActiveConnection = ConnectionString
        sProUserName = Request.Form("ProUserName")
        sanitizedProUserName = "'" & Replace(sProUserName, "'", "''") & "'"
        Response.Write(sanitizedProUserName)
        Response.End()
        IsUserNameLocked.Source = "SELECT IL_Date, IL_Timer, IL_NumOfTimes, ProUserName FROM PROFILE WHERE ProUserName =" & sanitizedProUserName
        IsUserNameLocked.CursorType = 2
        IsUserNameLocked.CursorLocation = 3
        IsUserNameLocked.LockType = 3
        IsUserNameLocked.Open
        if not IsUserNameLocked.eof then
            intNumOfIncorrectLogin = IsUserNameLocked("IL_NumOfTimes")
            InCorrectLoginDate = IsUserNameLocked("IL_Date")
            InCorrectLoginTime = IsUserNameLocked("IL_Timer")
        end if  
        IsUserNameLocked.close
        set IsUserNameLocked = nothing
    end if
%>
```

I attempted to convert it to:

```
If Request.QueryString("Action") = "Login" Then
    Dim IsUserNameLocked
    Set IsUserNameLocked = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    IsUserNameLocked.ActiveConnection = ConnectionString
    strSql = "SELECT IL_Date, IL_Timer, IL_NumOfTimes, ProUserName FROM PROFILE WHERE   ProUserName = ?"
    strSearch = Request.Form("ProUserName")
    set objCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")   
    objCommand.ActiveConnection = ConnectionString
    objCommand.CommandText = strSql 
    objCommand.Parameters(0).value = strSearch
    IsUserNameLocked.results = objCommand.Execute()
    IsUserNameLocked.CursorType = 2
    IsUserNameLocked.CursorLocation = 3
    IsUserNameLocked.LockType = 3
    IsUserNameLocked.Open
end if
```

But this did not work. I have been searching online for the past few hours attempting to find a method that properly works, but I'm getting no functioning results. If someone could please help with an implementation that properly parameterizes and protects against SQL injection, I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you need to .Append a parameter to a Command's parameter collection. Evidence:

```
>> Set oCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
>> WScript.Echo "# parameters", oCmd.Parameters.Count
>> oCmd.Parameters(0).Value = "no such thing"
>>
# parameters 0
Error Number:       3265
Error Description:  Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.
```

Do you use a global On Error Resume Next?